# Javascript error "Unexpected strict mode reserved word" while using d3.js with apache codrova

Tags: javascript, cordova, d3.js

I would like to use [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) for showing graphs in my apache cordova app. To avoid unnecessary traffic there is a local d3.min.js file loaded via

```
<script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However I got the javascript error while starting the app in the android emulator

*Android API-Level 22 (Android 5.1)*

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word  @d3.min.js:2
```

*Android API-Level 23 (Android 6)*

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token => @ d3.js:19
```

There is no "use strict" in my code. To verify the issue I created a bare cordova project, included d3.js with the code above and got the same error.

Any idears on how to load d3.js without using strict mode in cordova?

I am using

```
d3.js 6.3.0
Android Studio 4.1.1        
Cordova 10.0.0
```

with

```
"cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4"
```

Comment: Have you tried using the non-minified bundle (d3.js instead of d3.min.js)? Maybe this can help getting the reserved word the error is all about.

Comment: I did not test it up until now. The error still exists. Just in another line (d3.js:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word)

Comment: I have no clue right now. Looking at line 15 (`let delta = f;`)  one notices that this is the first line of the file containing an **ES6** language feature (`let`). In strict mode `let` became a reserved keyword in **ES5**, though. Not sure if this is the right path or where it is taking you, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Checked for different errors depending on Android API Level. They occur for API-Level 22 (Android 5.1) and API-Level 23 (Android 6.9). Edited the entry accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the installed android webview is an out-dated version of Chrome. While Android has an independently update-able webview starting in Android 5.0... it doesn't mean all users actually do install updates, and sometimes some vendors cut off updates after sometime.

If you're using Google API enabled emulators, you can login to the Google Play store and should receive updates, including android webview updates.

But you may also want to run d3.js through a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile modern JS features into more compatible version such as ES3 javasacript. This will convert usages of `let` to `var` for example, or `() => {}` arrow functions into traditional `function () {}` functions. This will make d3.js compatible with older webview versions that may be running on some of your clients.